# python2.7 + multiprocessing + selenium: restart process on exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing, phantomjs

I seem to be having issues with a python script that uses multiprocessing. What it essentially does is take a list of ID codes, and start processes that use Selenium and PhantomJS as the driver to navigate to a URL containing that ID code, extract data to individual csv files, then compile another csv file once all processes finish. Everything runs great, except sometimes one of the processes will return an exception that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "modtest.py", line 11, in worker
    do_work(item)
  File "/home/mdrouin/Dropbox/Work/Dev/Python/WynInvScrape/items.py", line 14, in do_work
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.py", line 72, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to GhostDriver")
```

I've tried working in ways to restart the process if an exception is raised, but what appears to be happening, regardless, is once the processes finish, the program hangs and doesn't move on, or do anything for that matter. I would essentially like to restart the ID number that is being searched for if the process crashes, and continue on when all processes are finished. Here is an extremely slimmed down version of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import multiprocessing
import datetime, time, csv, glob


num_procs = 8

def do_work(rsrt):

        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

        try:
            driver.get('http://www.example.com/get.php?resort=' + rsrt)

            rows = []

            for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
                if row.find('input', {'name': 'booksubmit'}):
                    wyncheckin = row.find('td', {'class': 'searchAvailDate'}).string
                    wynnights = row.find('td', {'class': 'searchAvailNights'}).string
                    wynroom = row.find('td', {'class': 'searchAvailUnitType'}).string
                    rows.append([wynresort, wyncheckin, wynroom])


            driver.quit()

            with open('/home/mdrouin/Dropbox/Work/Dev/Python/WynInvScrape/availability/'+rsrt+'.csv', 'wb') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)

            print 'Process ' + rsrt + ' End: ' + str(time.strftime('%c'))


        except:
            driver.quit()



def worker():
    for item in iter( q.get, None ):
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()
    q.task_done()


q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

procs = []

for i in range(num_procs):
    procs.append( multiprocessing.Process(target=worker) )
    procs[-1].daemon = True
    procs[-1].start()

source = ['0017', '0113', '0020', '0013', '0038', '1028', '0115', '0105', '0041', '0037', '0043', '2026', '0165', '0164',
        '0033', '0126', '0116', '0103', '9135', '0185', '0206', '0053', '0062', '1020', '0019', '0042', '2028', '0213',
        '0211', '0163', '0073', '2020', '0214', '2140', '0084', '0193', '0095', '0064', '0196', '0028', '0068', '0074']

for item in source:
    q.put(item)

q.join()

for p in procs:
    q.put( None )

q.join()

for p in procs:
    p.join()

print "Finished"
print 'Writting core output: ' + str(time.strftime('%c'))
with open('availability.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for csvfile in glob.glob('/home/mdrouin/Dropbox/Work/Dev/Python/WynInvScrape/availability/*.csv'):
        for line in open(csvfile, 'r'):
            outfile.write(line)

print 'Process End: ' + str(time.strftime('%c'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to tackle this sort of problem is with recurrent call to itself, something in lines of:

```
def do_work(rsrt):
    if failed:
        return do_work(rsrt)
```

Of course this will run until it resolves, so you might want to pass a counter and if it's above certain value just return false.

Comment: Would I add this to the bottom of the function? Or in a try/except within the function? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @crookedleaf: what I posted is a pseudocode, do not insert it anywhere  as it is only supposed to show the general idea. Which is simple - if your function call, call it again so in your case it would be in the except part.

Comment: After running a couple tests, seems to work perfect. Thank you so much! I had no clue you could call a function inside of itself. And sorry for the confusion on the placement. The "if" part threw me off a little.

Comment: @crookedleaf you are welcome. Just keep in mind that not implementing any sort of safety limitation inside this function may cause infinite recurrence which will eventually cause the whole thing to crash.

Comment: Will do. I built a 'while' loop into the exception. If the exception is raised, it will sleep for 10 seconds, then retry... no more than 5 times (in which case there's an if loop that sends me an email if 5 tries are attempted, then terminates).